# I have a ExternalTaskSensor ERROR,AirflowSensorTimeout

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have a ExternalTaskSensor ERROR,

first : DAG A.task1 tigger DAG B.task1,
second: DAG A.task3 wait until B.task2 success.

so I use ExternalTaskSensor ,
pic follow:
[enter image description here][1]

```
ExternalTaskSensor （task_id='xxx',external_dag_id='xxx',timeout='xxx',retries=1,allowed_states=['success'],check_existence=True,mode='reschedule',dag=dag）
```

I get A.task3 error this:

```
[2022-06-12,16:48:32 CST] xxxx info poking for tasks None in dag xiezhuan188 on 2022-06-11T08:01:00+00:00...
[2022-06-12,16:48:32 CST] xxxx Error: xxxxx AirflowSensorTimeout('snap . time is out.Dag id:{log_dag_id}"
```

the B.task2' log like this:

```
[2022-06-12,16:28:22 CST]xxxxx INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=xiezhuan188,task_id=xxxx,execution_date=202220612T080815,start_date=20220612T082822,end_date=20220612T082822
[2022-06-12,16:28:22 CST]XXXXX INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-06-12,16:28:22 CST]XXXXX INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Can help me : T.T
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JsOD.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcCrO.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu1iJ.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy66j.jpg
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZILT.jpg
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MKXT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

can you please share your code like in text, Moreover you are not using the external task sensor right, you have to use the time difference correctly for example Dag_B schedule_interval should be earlier than Dag_A. Otherwise, it will not work and i dont think you have mentioned the schedule interval, morevoer in DAG A the time execution delta is also not set properly read about it

Comment: yes, I had try execution_date_fn and execution_delta ，but failed !  I have add more Code pictures . thanks!

Comment: NOW, I SPLIT Dag A to( DAG A1 , Dag A2 ) DAG A1.task1 tigger DAG B.task1, and DAG B.task2 tigger DAG A2.  Stupid way  ：（

Comment: shared the solution please check and let me know if there is anything you cant understand thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay here i have wrtoe external task sensor with example of slave and master dag.
First create Slave dag  Dag_B   e.g

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import airflow.utils.dates
from datetime import  datetime,  timedelta


default_args = {
        "owner": "airflow", 
        "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
    }

with DAG(dag_id="CrossDAG_DAG_B", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *") as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(task_id="t1", bash_command="echo 'test' ")

    # dependencies:  its only 1 because there is not other task.
    t1
```

Now i will write Master Dag_A Which sense slave dag

```
##Master DAG
import pprint as pp
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
import airflow.utils.dates
from datetime import  datetime,  timedelta


"""[ 
    
This File contains code for cross dag dependencies where we have use external task sensor to create Cross DAG 
dependencies between 2 DAGs. Furthermore if we want dynamic cross DAG dependencies where one DAG will start 
at 12:00 Midnight and other one is scheduled at every 10 Minutes to perform this feat we can use execution_delta

Key Points for execution_delta
1.Dag_B schedule_interval should be earlier than Dag_A. Otherwise it will not work.
2.In execution the timedelta Object we can define the Hours and Minutes (its the difference between Dag_B and Dag_A 
Schedule Interval)
3.time difference with the previous execution to
        look at, the default is the same execution_date as the current task.
        For yesterday, use [positive!] datetime.timedelta(days=1)

]"""

default_args = {
        "owner": "airflow", 
        "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
    }

with DAG(dag_id="CrossDAG_DAG_A", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *") as dag:
    sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id= 'sensor',
        external_dag_id= "CrossDAG_DAG_B",
        external_task_id= 't1',
        execution_delta= timedelta(minutes =5)
    )

    last_task = DummyOperator(task_id= "last_task")


    sensor >> last_task
```

Use this and i have explained how this things work and how cna u use execution delta properly