# Complex Airflow Cross-DAG Dependency

Tags: python, airflow, etl, pipeline

In my Airflow there are 2 types of DAGs:

- 1st DAG Type (DT1) - loads data from source to Data Lake. These DAGs triggered by schedule.
- 2nd DAG Type (DT2) - takes data Data Lake and does some transformations\aggregations\etc. These DAGs also can be triggered by schedule, but only if all required DT1 in status "success"

What is the right way to implement next logic?

Three DT1s - triggered each hour. One DT2 - triggered one time per day (~10 or 11 PM). But DT2 can be triggered only if all three DT1s for past hour in status "success".

I'd prefer to implement it only with Airflow functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `ExternalTaskSensor` is designed for this.

```
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor
```

The documentation page is [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html#externaltasksensor) which shows its usage (specifying execution dates, success states etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You will use external task sesnor for this but the main catch will be how you use the time schedule between these dags as these are the main ingredients, Furthermore if we want dynamic cross DAG dependencies where one DAG will start
at 12:00 Midnight and other one is scheduled at every 10 Minutes Or every hour to perform this feat we can use execution_delta

Key Points for execution_delta
1.Dag_B schedule_interval should be earlier than Dag_A. Otherwise it will not work.
2.In execution the timedelta Object we can define the Hours and Minutes (its the difference between Dag_B and Dag_A
Schedule Interval)
3.time difference with the previous execution to
look at, the default is the same execution_date as the current task.
For yesterday, use [positive!] datetime.timedelta(days=1)

````
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
import airflow.utils.dates
from datetime import  datetime,  timedelta

 default_args = {
        "owner": "airflow", 
        "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
    }

with DAG(dag_id="CrossDAG_DAG_A", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *") as dag:
    sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id= 'sensor',
        external_dag_id= "CrossDAG_DAG_B",
        external_task_id= 't1',
        execution_delta= timedelta(minutes =5)
    )

    last_task = DummyOperator(task_id= "last_task")


    sensor >> last_task ```


you can create the second dag according to your requiremnt but i have shared the main logic here. moreover i have shared the complete code in anohter post youc an see that for more explaination.




[answere to another post][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597384/i-have-a-externaltasksensor-error-airflowsensortimeout/72601464?noredirect=1#comment128265090_72601464
````